# Bounded sequences without a convergent subsequence converging in a different metric

Tags: real-analysis

Given the metric $$d(x,y)=\text{min}\{1,|x-y|\}$$ on $\Bbb{R}$.There is a bounded sequence in $(\Bbb{R},d)$ without a convergent subsequence. Prove that a sequence in $(\Bbb{R},d)$ converges iff it converges in the standard metric on $\Bbb{R}$.

My try: Say $\{p_n\}$ is a bounded sequence in $(\Bbb{R},d)$. Assume it converges in $\Bbb{R}$(with the standard metric. That means for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists an integer $N$ such for $n\geq N$, $|p_n-p|<\epsilon$. Also since $\{p_n\}$ is bounded there exists $K$ such that $d(p_i,p_j)\leq K$. Now I was thinking taht what all can happen to the metric and can I used the fact that it converges under the standard metric. But I was not able to go much farther.

Is this idea correct? What else should I do?

Comment: The direction you've attempted is easier than you're making it: it is essentially immediate from the fact that $d(x,y) \leq |x-y|$. The other direction is a bit more difficult: you essentially need to show that if $d(x,y)$ is small *enough* then $|x-y|$ is also small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are on the right track but your notation is a little clunky. Note that if $p_n \to p$ in the standard metric, then $|p_n-p| < 1$ for all $n$ large, so $d(p_n,p) = |p_n-p|$ for all $n$ large, and hence $d(p_n,p) \to 0$. On the other hand, if $d(p_n,p) \to 0$, then we must have $d(p_n,p) < 1$ for all $n$ large, so it must be that $d(p_n,p) = |p_n-p|$ for all $n$ large, and hence $|p_n-p| = d(p_n,p) \to 0$ and we have convergence in the standard metric.